# Função para imprimir a quantidade de caracteres em uma string bidimensional

Tags: c, string, funções, ponteiro

Pelo enunciado do exercício, preciso obrigatoriamente usar como o segundo argumento `char **strings`, acredito que aí esteja minha confusão, em manipulá-la para contar o tamanho da *string*. (Fiz outros testes com o segundo argumento como `char strings[][str_size]` e tudo correu bem, mas como disse, preciso usar o argumento como sendo `char **strings`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define str_size 127

void imprimeTamString(int numStrings, char **strings)
{
    int i, j;
    int tamanho;

    printf("\n---Tamanhos---\n\n");
    for(i=0; i<numStrings; i++)
    {
        tamanho=0;
        for(j=0; j<str_size; j++)
        {
            if(strings[i][j]!='\0')
                tamanho=tamanho+1;
            else
                break;
        }
        printf("String %d - Tamanho = %d\n", i+1, tamanho);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;//numero de strings//

    printf("Deseja entrar com quantas strings? ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    char *str1, **str2;
    char string[n][str_size];
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("String %d = ", i+1);
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(string[i]);
    }

    str1=string[0];
    str2=&str1;

    imprimeTamString(n, str2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: E existe alguma restrição para não usar o `strlen()`?

Comment: Não há, mas também não consegui fazer usando strlen()

Comment: Chame com: imprimeTamString(n, string); que você estará chamando a função com um ponteiro para um ponteiro de char.

Comment: @MarcoAntonioSchneider e tem que ser mesmo `char**`? Algum motivo para ser sim: Você não está interpretando isso desta forma mas poder ser de outra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saudações

A sua função de contagem de caractere está funcionando corretamente. O que está ocorrendo ai é que você não está alocando de forma adequada a matriz que irá armazenar a sua String.

Esse é um erro muito comum cometido por pessoas que costumam trabalhar com linguagens que o simples fato de declarar uma variável já implica em sua alocação de memória, em C não é assim que funciona.

O que você terá que fazer ANTES de começar a usar o sua matriz chamada string é INICIALIZAR cada elemento com o número adequado de bytes para armazenar as strings que serão digitadas.

O que você que fazer é algo assim:

```
char* string[n];
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
  string[i] = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*str_size);
}
```

A passagem do parâmetro para a função está correto. Você não precisa usar & quando é string uma vez que o nome da variável já aponta para o ponteiro onde tem o primeiro caractere da string!

Boa sorte com o seu exercício!

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado, o problema estava mesmo na falta de alocação

Answer (score 2):

Você pode simplificar bem o código e evitar alguns erros. Além de não usar um função que é inadequada para leitura de dados. Mas o que está complicando é que está criando um *array* no *stack* e depois lendo como ponteiro de ponteiros. Se puder mudar para ler como *array* de *strings* funcionará:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define STR_SIZE 127

void imprimeTamString(int numStrings, char (*strings)[STR_SIZE + 1]) {
    printf("\n---Tamanhos---\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < numStrings; i++) printf("String %d - Tamanho = %d\n", i + 1, (int)strlen(strings[i]));
}

int main() {
    int numStrings;
    printf("Deseja entrar com quantas strings? ");
    scanf("%d", &numStrings);
    scanf("%*c");
    char strings[numStrings][STR_SIZE + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < numStrings; i++) {
        printf("String %d = ", i + 1);
        fgets(strings[i], STR_SIZE, stdin);
        strings[i][strcspn(strings[i], "\n")] = 0;
    }
    imprimeTamString(numStrings, strings);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/PsxhmY). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/ArrayString). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/LenInArray.c).

Se tiver que ser ponteiro de ponteiro mesmo pode fazer assim, mas aí terá que alocar as *strings* no *heap*:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define STR_SIZE 127

void imprimeTamString(int numStrings, char **strings) {
    printf("\n---Tamanhos---\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < numStrings; i++) printf("String %d - Tamanho = %d\n", i + 1, (int)strlen(strings[i]));
}

int main() {
    int numStrings;
    printf("Deseja entrar com quantas strings? ");
    scanf("%d", &numStrings);
    scanf("%*c");
    char *strings[numStrings];
    for (int i = 0; i < numStrings; i++) {
        printf("String %d = ", i + 1);
        strings[i] = malloc(STR_SIZE + 1);
        fgets(strings[i], STR_SIZE, stdin);
        strings[i][strcspn(strings[i], "\n")] = 0;
    }
    imprimeTamString(numStrings, strings);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Qkjwhi). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/ArrayStrings). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Function/ArrayStrings.c).

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa entender alguns conceitos básicos antes, os quais são:

**O que é uma matriz?**

> Matriz é a uma estrutura de dados do tipo vetor com duas ou mais dimensões. Os itens de uma matriz tem que ser todos do mesmo tipo de dado. Na prática, as matrizes formam tabelas na memória.

**Como fazer a Declaração de Matrizes?**

> Você possui algumas formas de declarar a matriz, as quais são:
>
> - 1) `char matriz[LINHA][COLUNA]`
> - 2) `int **matriz`
>
> Onde o **(1)** seria a mesma coisa que o **(2)**, porém o **(1)** você é **obrigado a inicializa-las com os seus tamanhos**(`LINHA` & `COLUNA`). Logo o **(2)** **não tem necessidade e você pode utilizar o mesmo para fazer** [alocação dinâmica](https://pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programar_em_C%2B%2B/Aloca%C3%A7%C3%A3o_din%C3%A2mica_de_mem%C3%B3ria).

**Outras formas de declaração de Matrizes:**

> Caso você não necessite de uma entrada (input) de dados para a inserção na matriz, isto é, você tenha os dados fixos e que sempre serão constantes, você pode fazer desta forma:

```
const char matriz[5][5] = { {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'}, { 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J' } }
```

**Como acessar os elementos da Matriz?**

> Você precisará de um algoritmo **O(n²)**, ou seja, dois for aninhados, um para a `LINHA` e outro para a `COLUNA`, como por exemplo:

```
const char matriz[5][5] = { {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'}, { 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J' } }

for(int linha = 0; linha < 5; linha++) {
    for(int coluna = 0; coluna < 5; coluna++) {
        //CÓDIGO
    }
}
```

Utilize a biblioteca `<string>` para verificar o tamanho da mesma, como por exemplo:

```
string str ("Testando String");
cout << "TAMANHO DA STRING: " << str.size() << " bytes.\n";
```

- [FONTE OFICIAL: CPLUSPLUS - STRING SIZE](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/size/)
- [FONTE OFICIAL: PUCRS - VETORES & MATRIZES](https://www.inf.pucrs.br/~pinho/LaproI/Vetores/Vetores.htm)